# Problem with Adobe Audition 1.5 (running under Wine)

Tags: sound, lubuntu, wine, lenovo

I'd had always been using Adobe Audition 1.5 (software created to Windows), and now I use it with Lubuntu through Wine. I use it on my Sony Vaio laptop and my Lenovo desktop.

My problem is since two weeks ago I can't read/play audio files (doesn't matter the format, mp3, wav, ac3, wma, etc.) with Adobe Audition on my Lenovo desktop.

I saved some audio (music songs from a vinyl), with Adobe Audition in the Lenovo and I put it on the normal "Music" folder.

The files are absolutely right, because I can read/play it with Gnome MPlayer and Audacity. Also, I copied the files to an USB pendrive and I can read/play it with any other PC, any audio software (Adobe Audition, Audacity, Windows Media Player, Gnome MPlayer, WinAmp, VLC Player, etc.)

I re-installed Adobe Audition on the Lenovo PC, but the problem remains the same.

The problem is specifically with the Lenovo installation.

The Lenovo desktop PC is the following configuration:

```
Model: M-55e 9645-QTS.
CPU: Genuine Intel Core 2 Duo at 1.8 GHZ (64 bit).
RAM: 3 GB.
Audio: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7.
Video: Intel Corporation 82946GZ/GL.
```

(Both audio and video devices are incorporated on the PC Motherboard)

I use Lubuntu 15.04, 64 bit, with all the today upgrades.

I don't know what to do.

Some help, please!!!

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!!!!!!!

Juan

Answer (score 0):

Please, clarify some things is it only in wine that adobe audition refuses to play audio files or does same happen in windows too. Since the problem mostly seems to be restricted to adobe auditions i would say its more or so wine related.

Try checking your sound setting of wine and see if you are able to play something else

> $ winecfg

Also try clearing all your wine setting and then installing adobe auditions again(WARNING THIS WILL DELETE ALL WINE DATA)

> rm -r ~/.wine
>
> sudo  apt-get purge wine
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo  apt-get install wine

Comment: I don't have Windows installed on the Lenovo desktop PC. I re-installed Wine (and all its components) and I re-installed Audition, too, and the problem remains the same.

Comment: @Juan are you sure that you are able to hear sound from other applications in wine .....the sound issue could very much be wine related

Comment: Problem solved!!!

Comment: Problem solved!!! Dear gang, thank you so much for your help. It wasn't a Lubuntu issue, wasn't a Wine issue. I could fix the problem reading an old paper notebook I still have with DOS and Windows issues. I select all the audio files of the Music folder, cut and paste to a new folder, and... Now Audition read and save any audio on the new folder!!! I don't know why Audition can't read from some specific folders (I guess is something related with the folder name, but I'm not sure). So... Problem solved!!! Thank you so much for your comments!!! Greetings & Bleesings from Chile!!!!!!!

Comment: It's good to know that your problem is solved.